# Intercept return-key when on a multiline TextBox, preventing close of the dialog

Tags: .net, winforms, events

I have a .net WinForm dialog, which displays some TextBoxes (some of them are *Multiline*), a button marked as *AcceptButton* and one marked as *CancelButton*.

When you hit the return key, the onClick event of the *AcceptButton* is triggered and the dialog closes.

The matter is that the onClick event is triggered EVEN IF the user tries to insert a new paragraph in a multiline TextBox. The only way to prevent the close of the form is pressing CTRL + Return.

This is a manifestly a bug of the WinForm TextBox control.
For example a DataGridView correctly catches the Return-key and doesn't passes it to the WinForm dialog.

Treid *Select()*, *Focus()*, overriding *PreProcessMessage*, *ProcessKeyMessage* (which strangely don't even fire). No luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me stupid!

There is a boolean property of the TextBox named *AcceptReturn*.

I think it should be autochecked by VS when checking *Multiline*.

Answer (score 0):

I solved checking for Focus state + ReturnKey state in the onClick event handler of the *Accept Button*

```
If (UdaNoteTextBox.Focused) Then
    Dim returnKey As NullFX.Win32.KeyStateInfo = NullFX.Win32.KeyboardInfo.GetKeyState(Keys.Enter)
    If (returnKey.IsPressed) Then
        Dim caretFinalPos As Int32 = UdaNoteTextBox.SelectionStart + 2
        UdaNoteTextBox.Text = UdaNoteTextBox.Text.Substring(0, UdaNoteTextBox.SelectionStart) + vbCrLf + UdaNoteTextBox.Text.Substring(UdaNoteTextBox.SelectionStart + UdaNoteTextBox.SelectionLength)
        UdaNoteTextBox.SelectionStart = caretFinalPos
        UdaNoteTextBox.SelectionLength = 0
        UdaNoteTextBox.ScrollToCaret()
        Return
    End If
End If
```

To check ReturnKey state I used this class, which imports the old User32.dll, as this function seems not to exist in the .net framework.

http://sanity-free.com/17/obtaining_key_state_info_in_dotnet_csharp_getkeystate_implementation.html